# codeigniter static pages tutorial on MAMP not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, mamp

Hey guys im simply following the static pages tutorial for codeigniter and im getting a 404 not found

```
<?php

class Pages extends CI_Controller {


    public function view($page = 'home') {

        if(!file_exists(APPPATH . '/views/pages/' . $page . '.php')) {
            //page isnt here
            show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
    }
}

?>
```

all i have is what the guide is telling me to copy. I havent gotten to the routing yet because nothing is working. Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Whats the URL your visiting to get the output?

Comment: http://localhost:8888/CodeIgniter/index.php/pages/view i only have the codeigniter folder in my htdocs folder according to mamp documentation @CiaranSynnott

Comment: If you remove `show_404()` and put `echo 1;` do you get 1?

Comment: @CiaranSynnott i do get 1. i even `var_dump(!file_exists(APPPATH . '/views/pages/' . $page . '.php'));` and it returns `true` so idk what to do

Comment: What do you get if your remove `if(!file_exists(APPPATH . '/views/pages/' . $page . '.php')) {
            //page isnt here
            show_404();
        }`

Comment: @CiaranSynnott i get the following `An Error Was Encountered

Unable to load the requested file: pages/home.php`

Comment: Ok So maybe the file is called Home.php? It says it can't find the file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95427/discussion-between-hello-world-and-ciaransynnott).

Comment: Are you sure that the file "Codeigniter/application/views/pages/home.php" exists?